Proving that a function defined as an expectation is Lipschitz
I would like to prove this
Let $G(y)\doteq\mathbb{E}[X|\gamma X+\gamma^{1/2}Z=y]$ where $Z\sim\mathcal{N }(0,1)$ and $X\sim\pi(x)$ where $\pi(x)$ has bounded support. $Z$ and $X$ are indepenedent. I want to prove that $G(y)$ is $||G||_{\infty}^2$-Lipschitz and non-decreasing.
This is my attempt. I denote $p_Y(y)$ the density of $Y=\gamma X+\gamma^{1/2}Z$. Since $X$ and $Z$ are indip. $$p_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\gamma^{3/2}} \pi(\cdot/\gamma)*\phi(\cdot/\gamma^{1/2})$$
I want to use Tweedie's formula $$\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=y+\gamma\partial_y\log p_Y(y)$$
So I have a more explicit expression for the function $G(y)=y+\gamma\partial_y\log p_Y(y)=y+\gamma\frac{1}{p_Y(y)}\partial_yp_Y(y)$
From here I've tried to take the derivative of $G$ and I hoped that is non negative and bounded by $||G||_\infty^2$ so that I can have the thesis, so $$\partial_yG(y)=1+\gamma[-(\frac{1}{p_y(y)})^2(\partial_yp_Y(y))^2+\frac{1}{p_Y(y)}\partial_{yy}p_Y(y)]=1+\gamma[-(\frac{G(y)-y}{\gamma})^2+\frac{1}{p_Y(y)}\partial_{yy}p_Y(y)]$$
Now I write explicitly
$$p_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\gamma^{3/2}}\int\pi(x/\gamma)\exp[-(y-x)^2/\gamma]dx$$
This is the convolution of $\pi(x/\gamma)\in L^1$ and $\exp(-x^2/\gamma)\in C^\infty\cap L^\infty$ and its derivatives belong to $L^\infty$ as well. So $p_Y(y)\in C^\infty$ and its derivative is calculated simply "taking the derivative inside the integral" so
$$\partial_{yy}p_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\gamma^{3/2}}\int\pi(x/\gamma)\partial_{yy}\exp[-(y-x)^2/\gamma]dx=\frac{1}{\gamma^{3/2}}\int\pi(x/\gamma)\exp[-(y-x)^2/\gamma]\frac{4(y-x)^2-2\gamma}{\gamma^2}dx$$
In conclusion I would like to prove that
$$1+\gamma[-(\frac{G(y)-y}{\gamma})^2+\frac{1}{p_Y(y)}\partial_{yy}p_Y(y)]$$
is bounded by $||G||_{\infty}^2$ and non negative, but I cannot conclude? Am I on the right path?

I've made some progression and ended here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4958800/founding-a-inequality-between-ratio-of-integral-function

A partial answer for the non-decreasing part of the question.
First, let us look at the
the special case $\gamma = 1$.
For $y \in \mathbb{R}$ :
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[X \mid X + Z = y] = \mathbb{E}[X + Z - Z \mid X+ Z = y] = y - \mathbb{E}[Z \mid X + Z = y]
\end{equation*}
Now working on $\mathbb{E}[Z \mid X + Z = y]$.
The joint density $p_{(Z,X)}(z,x) = \pi(x) \phi(z)$ holds by independence. Here $\pi$ is the Lebesgue density of $X$ and $\phi$ is the $N(0,1)$ density :
\begin{equation*}
\phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}
\end{equation*}
Using a transformation, we can show that $p_{(Z, X+Z)}(z,y) = \phi(z)\pi(y-2z)$. So :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&\mathbb{E}[Z\mid Y = y] = \int_{\mathbb{R}}z \frac{\phi(z)\pi(y-2z)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(z)\pi(y-z)dz}dz = \frac{\frac{1}{4}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(y-u)\phi(\frac{y-u}{2})\pi(u)du}{\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi(y-u)\pi(u)du} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{4}(y-X)\phi(\frac{y-X}{2})]}{\mathbb{E}[\phi(y-X)]}
\\ & \leqslant \frac{\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{4}(y-X)\phi(\frac{y-X}{2})]}{\mathbb{E}[\phi(\frac{y-X}{2})]} \leqslant \frac{1}{4} \|y-X \|_{\infty} \leqslant \frac{1}{4}y + \frac{1}{4}\|X \|_{\infty}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
We have used Hölder's inequality and the fact that $\phi(\frac{x}{2}) \geqslant \phi(x)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. By the assumption that $\pi$ has bounded support, $\|X \|_{\infty} < \infty$. Therefore :
\begin{equation*}
G(y) = \mathbb{E}[X \mid X + Z = y] \geqslant  \frac{3}{4}y - \frac{1}{4}\|X \|_{\infty}
\end{equation*}
The proof that $G(y)$ is non-decreasing for $\gamma = 1$ is complete.
For general $\gamma > 0$, We have the same result. $G(y)$ is increasing if and only if $G(\frac{y}{\gamma})$ is. So the only change in the above proof is that $\phi$ will depend on $\gamma$. We should be able to copy things word to word .
For the Lipschitz part, it seems you will have to differentiate the quotient and do a lot more computation .
