Founding a inequality between ratio of integral function
Let $A(y)\doteq \int x\varphi_{\gamma x,\gamma}(y)\tilde{\pi}_{0}(dx)$ and $B(y)\doteq \int\varphi_{\gamma x,\gamma}(y)\tilde{\pi}_{0}(dx)$ where $\tilde{\pi}_0$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ concentrated on a bounded set and $\varphi_{m,\sigma^2}$ the density of a Gaussian with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
$A(y),B(y)\in C^\infty$ because are  convolution of $L^1$ and a $L^\infty\cap C^\infty$ function whose derivatives are in $L^\infty$ and I can calculate the derivatives.
$\gamma\partial_yA(y)=-\int x\varphi_{\gamma x,\gamma}(y)(y-\gamma x)\tilde{\pi}_{0}(dx)=-yA(y)+\gamma C(y)$ where$C(y)\doteq \int x^2\varphi_{\gamma x,\gamma}(y)(y-\gamma x)\tilde{\pi}_{0}(dx)$
$\gamma\partial_yB(y)=-\int\varphi_{\gamma x,\gamma}(y)(y-\gamma x)\tilde{\pi}_{0}(dx)=-yB(y)+\gamma A(y)$
Let $F(y)=A(y)/B(y)$ then
$\partial_yF(y)=\frac{B(y)\partial_yA(y)-A(y)\partial_y B(y)}{B^2(y)}=\frac{CB}{B^2}-\frac{A^2}{B^2}$.  It' simple to prove that $C/B\geq A^2/B^2$ (for example Jensen applied to the convex function $x^2$ and the measure $\varphi_{\gamma x,\gamma}(y)\tilde{\pi}_{0}(dx)$. I would like to prove that $F(y)$ is $||F||_\infty ^2$-Lipschitz by proving that it's derivative is bounded by that constant but I'm stuck here $|\partial_y F(y)|=C/B- A^2/B^2=C/B-F^2$
